# ssrs report error "An error occurred during local report processing."

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ssrs-2008

i want to export `rdl` into `pdf` and reports have query and dataset everything sets on report. i am using this code but it's give me an error

```
ReportViewer reportViewer = new ReportViewer();
reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
reportViewer.SizeToReportContent = true;
reportViewer.Width = Unit.Percentage(900);
reportViewer.Height = Unit.Percentage(900);
string filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/Reports/Reports.rdl");
reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/Reports/Reports.rdl");

Warning[] warnings;
string[] streamids;
string mimeType;
string encoding;
string filenameExtension;

byte[] bytes = reportViewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension, out streamids, out warnings);

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
 {
   fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
 }
```

please help me how to fix this..?

Comment: There is something wrong with the parameters you put in OR the stored procedure...best thing you could do is go on the SQL server your stored procedure is located on, then activate "Enable remote errors"....this allows you to get more in detail error messages.

Comment: my rdl have this query and select firstname, lastname from users

Comment: Also im assuming you have a seperate server, ONLY for ssrs ?(seperate from the server the DB your datasource is pointing to), if so, se the reportviewer's processing mode to Remote

Comment: yes off course @BernardWalters

Comment: but i have change the ProcessingMode.Remote but it's not working

Comment: i think i got it, use ServerReport , not LocalReport...Ill post my code below(i used the following in my code)

Comment: what server report..?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136934/discussion-between-bernard-walters-and-arsalan-qaiser).